# Почему не выводятся посты?

Tags: laravel

Почему-то не выводятся посты на странице категории. Я могу получить только количество постов, но не сами посты.

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title')
{{ $category->name}}
@endsection

@section('content')
<h1>{{ $category->name }}</h1>
<h3>{{ $category->posts()->count() }}</h3>
@foreach($category->posts() as $post)
<h5>{{ $post->title }}</h5>
@endforeach

@endsection
```

```
public function getCategory($slug){
        $category = Category::where('slug', $slug)->first();
        return view('blog.category', compact('category'));
    }
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте использовать предварительную загрузку [with](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading), проверив сначала что данные постов у категории действительно есть.

Comment: Я не очень понимаю, как использовать эту предварительную загрузку

Comment: потому что `$category->posts()` это вы получите билдер запроса, а не результат выполнения. Либо делайте `$category->posts()->get()` либо просто `$category->posts`. И прочитайте что такое ленивая загрузка

Comment: Я пытаюсь сделать через `$category->posts`,  но это не работает